# join + leave command leave is not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

Here i have a code to join and leave but leave does not work

(join is working, leave is working too but it does crash every time when he wanna leave)

```
> client.on('message', async message => {
    if (!message.guild) return;

    if (message.content === `${config.prefix}komm`) {
        message.react('☘️');
        if (message.member.voice.channel) {
            const connection = await message.member.voice.channel.join();
        } else {
            message.reply('Du huens geh mal erst in nen channel');
        }
    }
});

client.on('message', async message => {
    if (!message.guild) return;

    if (message.content === `${config.prefix}geh`) {
        message.react('☘️');

        if (!message.guild.me.voice.channel.leave()) {
        message.reply("bin ja schon weg ya salame!");
        message.react('☘️');
        

        } else {
            !message.reply("warte, bin nirgendwo drin!");
            message.channel.send()
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Why do you await join but not leave?

Comment: Why do you have a if statement that is `if (!message.guild.me.voice.channel.leave())`? shouldnt you check `if (connection)` and then `connection.disconnect()`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your Answer :)

**Based on** [Discord.js Guide](https://discordjs.guide/voice/the-basics.html#joining-voice-channels)

```
// Discord.js v11.
// Inside of Message Event.

if (message.content === `${config.prefix}join`) {
    if (!message.guild) return;
    if (message.member.voiceChannel) {
        message.member.voiceChannel.join()
            .then(connection => { // Connection is an instance of VoiceConnection
                message.reply('I am connected');
            })
            .catch(console.log);
    } else {
        message.reply('You need to join a voice channel first!');
    }
}

if (message.content === `${config.prefix}leave`) {
    if (!message.guild) return;
    // check if the bot is connected to a voice channel
    if (message.guild.me.voiceChannel !== undefined) {
        message.guild.me.voiceChannel.leave();
        message.reply("Left.");
    } else {
        message.reply("I'm not connected to a voice channel.");
    }
}
```

```
// Discord.js v12
// Async message Event and await the command.
client.on('message', async message => {
    if (!message.guild) return;
    if (message.content === `${config.prefix}join`) {
        // Join the same voice channel of the author of the message
        if (message.member.voice.channel) {
            const connection = await message.member.voice.channel.join();
            await message.channel.send("Connected."); // await message.reply("Connected.");
            // REST OF YOUR CODE
        }
    }
    if (message.content === `${config.prefix}leave`) {
        if(message.guild.me.voice.channel !== undefined) {
            await message.guild.me.voice.channel.leave(); // disconnect();
            await message.channel.send("Left");
        }
    }
});
```